# How can I count the number of boxes in a PNG image using Numpy and avoid nested loops?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to be more efficient with my code. I have a PNG and I want to cut the image in boxes.

The goal is to count the number of boxes where I have at least one **none** black pixel. I have only one variable N.

The variable defines the length of each boxes. If we let P be the bigger length of my image then the length of each boxes is P/N.

We also cut the image such that there is a box in the upper left corner.

[image]

Let's imagine that this rectangle is the image. In the case of N=3, the boxes appear as squares with one of the black segments as a side. Although this may seem odd, the 3 boxes cut off at the bottom are analysed in the code.

Here is a picture I am using.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
from skimage import io
import numpy as np

def count_boxes(img, N):
      t=0
      i,j,k = img.shape
      step=int(max(i,j)/N)
      for k1 in range(0, i, step):
         for k2 in range(0, j, step):
            if (img[k1:k1+step,k2:k2+step] != 0).any():
               t += 1
      return t

I = io.imread('England.png')
print(count_boxes(I,1000))
```

For me, it is slow. The problem is my two nested loops. I want to get rid of them but I don't know how I can achieve that. I would say that Numpy broadcasting could help but I don't see how in this situation.

N is defined to be less than one of the side of the image.

Answer (score -1):

You can't get rid of the nested loops*. You're forced to check every pixel in the image in the worst case which is going to be slow. Graphics is pretty intensive and checking every pixel in an image is always going to be expensive.

If speed is really an issue you could look into shaders- offloading parallelizable things like graphics/images to the GPU can lead to some immense gains in performance but they can be finnicky to setup/implement. I think you could potentially see a lot of performance increase if you used a compute shader to check for non black pixels in your boxes, but it might end up being slower as N gets smaller since dispatching shaders can be expensive so it depends on your own case.

There could be some other performance gains with some numpy trickery but I'm not familiar enough with numpy to say.

* You can put this in a single for loop with some clever indexing, but you'll still be doing the same number of iterations so there's no point in sacrificing the readability. Nested for loops is commonplace for graphics.